# How to request User Info from IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4, claims

I have a basic log-in flow using the `ResourceOwnerPassword` grant type.  The user can log-in, have their password validated and gets a token that they can use to access the API.  I'm now trying to pass a claim back to the client so that I can determine what kind of user I'm dealing with, but I'm getting an error that I believe to be an issue with the scope of the client (although I can't see what).

The code below is abridged to avoid pages and pages of code, but I believe it contains everything relevant.  This is the identity server set-up:

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()       
    .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerHelper.GetClients())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerHelper.GetApiResources())
    .AddTestUsers(IdentityServerHelper.GetUsers())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(
          IdentityServerHelper.GetIdentityResources());
```

The helper methods:

```
internal static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    var clients = new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "MyClientApp",                    
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,                    
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "myApi",
                "Role",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId
                /*
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                */
            }
        }
    };
}

internal static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new List<IdentityResource> {
        new IdentityResource {
            Name = "Role",
            UserClaims = new List<string> { JwtClaimTypes.Role },

        }
    };
}

internal static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
{
    var users = new List<TestUser>
    {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Username = "user",
                Password = "pass",
                Claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Role1")
                }
            },
```

The idea is to return `Role1` to the client.  Here's the client code:

```
_discoveryResponse = await _httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
{
    Address = "https://localhost:5021",               
    Policy =
    {                    
        ValidateIssuerName = false,
    }                
});

var response = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = _discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "MyClientApp",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = "openid Role myApi",
    UserName = username,
    Password = password
});

if (response.IsError)
{
    return false;  // When specifying openid, get invalid scope here
}

_accessToken = response.AccessToken;                                    

. . . 

var userInfo = await _httpClient.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest()
{
    Address = _discoveryResponse.UserInfoEndpoint,
    Token = _accessToken
});

// userInfo is returning "Forbidden" here.
```

EDIT:

When specifying openid in the scope, I get the following error in the Identity Server logs:

> fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator[0]
>         Requested scope not allowed: openid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add at least `openid` scope when you request a token. Changing code like below probably solves the problem.

```
var clients = new List<Client>
{
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "MyClientApp",                    
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,                    
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedScopes =
        {
            "myApi",
            "Role",
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId
        }
    }
};

var response = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = _discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "MyClientApp",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = "openid Role myApi",
    UserName = username,
    Password = password
});
```

You can see source code part from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Validation/Default/UserInfoRequestValidator.cs#L47

Comment: I had sort of come to that conclusion myself.  However, when I add that I get an error of "invalid scope" and can't even log-in.  As you can see, I did play about with adding an AllowedScope for OpenId, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you add openid both client configuration and token request?

Comment: Yes - if by "Client Configuration" you mean setting up the new list of clients.

Comment: In that case, yes

Comment: It should be either Role or myApi is not configured on idsrv. You can include role claim in myApi scope. But 'Role' is not a valid scope if you have not added it to idsrv. There might be "roles" scope configured in the samples. In that case you should request "openid roles myApi"

Comment: Surely, as long as I'm consistent, it makes no difference if it's roles or Role?

Comment: I tried various combinations - roles, role, Role and kept it consistent across the requested scope and the client's AllowedScope